# How do I get the program to use the default (press Return key) and allow the user to enter there own values?

Tags: c++

I'm having some issues with the following program. When I use the <kbd>Return</kbd> key, everything works fine. However, when I try to type in those same values, it doesn't work. Before I programmed it to accept the <kbd>Return</kbd> key, the typed data worked. It seems I can only get one or the other to work, but not both, in the same program.

```cpp
//#include Statement(s)
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//using Statement
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //variable declaration(s)
    int cookies, boxes, cookieTotal, boxTotal, containerTotal, cookiesLeft, boxesLeft;

    //executable statements
    //inputs
    cout << "Press Enter to use the default setting of 24 or input the number of cookies per box: ";
    if (cin.get() == '\n') { // detect 'enter' default
        cookies = 24;
        cout << "24" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cin >> cookies;
    }
    
    cout << "Press Enter to use the default setting of 75 or input the number of box per container: ";
    if (cin.get() == '\n') { // detect 'enter' default
        boxes = 75;
        cout << "75" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cin >> boxes;
    }

    cout << "Input the total about of cookies: ";
    cin >> cookieTotal;

    //processes
    boxTotal = cookieTotal / cookies;
    containerTotal = boxTotal / boxes;
    cookiesLeft = cookieTotal - (boxTotal * 24);
    boxesLeft = boxTotal - (containerTotal * 75);

    //outputs
    cout << "The total number of boxes: " << boxTotal << endl; 
    cout << "The total number of containers: " << containerTotal << endl;
    cout << "Leftover cookies: " << cookiesLeft << endl;
    cout << "Leftover boxes: " << boxesLeft << endl;

    //return statement
    char q;
    cout << "\nPress any key to Exit.";
    cin.ignore(2, '\n');
    cin.get(q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The default behaviour of ther `>>` operator is to read in one white-space delimited token and discard all preceding whitespace. Newline is  whitespace, so you can't read a newline with `>>`... Unless you tack on [`noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws).

Comment: If you use `get()` to try to detect ENTER, you will end up reading in the user's first digit, which will then not be available for `>>` to read in.  I would use `std::getline()` to read in input up to the ENTER to a string, and if the string is not empty then convert it to an integer with `std::stoi()`, eg: `getline(cin, input); if (input.empty()) { input = "24"; } cookies = stoi(input);`, and the same for `boxes` , etc

Comment: Formatted input using `<<`, character oriented input like `cin.get()`, and string-oriented input such as `cin.getline()` are distinct styles that handle whitespace differently (`<<` ignores whitespace and returns the first non-whitespace character, `cin.get()` returns whitespace characters to the caller, `cin.getline()` stops at a newline without reading it).  Your code mixes styles which causes problems like you're seeing - depending on user input.  The solution is to NEVER mix input styles on a stream (e.g. read all data from `cin` using string-oriented input, and then parse the string).